# This sort() method in my if statement giving me Non-static method 'sort(java.util.Comparator<? super E>)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, list, sorting

Trying to understand why this sort method isn't working.

Should I be trying a separate sorting algorithm?

Comment: Where does your List.sort come from?

Comment: @DanielWosch Sorry, I posted a previous version. I updated it. getAdministrations is a List.

Comment: Note that `.collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0)` can be better replaced with `.findFirst()` (and appropriate handling for retrieving the value from the `Optional`)

Answer (score 2):

The method `List<E>.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)` is a (default) *instance* method of interface `java.util.List`. That means, the "subject" of the method needs to be an actual object that performs the method. And it requires a `Comparator` as an argument. In your context, the correct invocation would be `inc.getAdministrations().sort(X)`, with `X` being replaced with the actual `Comparator` to be used for the comparisons during sorting.

Alternatively, you could try `Collections.sort(inc.getAdministrations())` which would use the natural ordering.

If you want to stick to `List.sort()` but use natural ordering, you could use this:
`inc.getAdministrations().sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());`.